# How can I reach debug log in Visual Studio (Xamarin), with Android emulator devices?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, mobile

I am newbie in mobile development, but I've already made C# desktop applications. I try to make mobile apps, but unfortunately I can't reach Device log because of this:
https://ibb.co/59bzp4L

I don't have devices in my device log, therefore I can't see the error messages etc... 
I really don't know, how can I log my messages on Xamarin, I read an article about that, but if I can't reach my android emulator devices, I can't debugging. 
Any suggestion?

So again, I read this article, and I understood:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=windows

But I don't have any devices in my device log, as you see on the picture.

C#, Visual Studio 2017, Xamarin, Android_Accelerated_x86_oreo (Android 8,1 - Api 27)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried clicking the play button in the logcat/device log window?
I assume the emulation is working fine but you can't get logs out?
Try playing the logcat and use breakpoints in the code to slowly step through and see if you get any errors.

You might also need ADB drivers.

Comment: Yes, I didn't have ADB driver, thanks for your answer! :)